# Find the probability P($x\ge2$) if $p_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}(p_n)$.

Tags: probability, statistics

looking for some advice on this problem:

*"Let $p_n, n = 0, 1, 2, . . .$ , be the probability that an automobile policyholder will file for n claims in a five-year period. The actuary involved makes the assumption that $p_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}(p_n)$. What is the probability that the holder will file two or more claims during this period?"*

So far, I've used the complement to show that $P(x\ge2)=1-[P(0)+P(1)]$.  Using the actuary's assumption, that is simplified into $P(x\ge2)=1-[P(0)+\frac{1}{4}P(0)]$.

What I don't see is where to proceed from here. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $p_{n+1}=\frac14 p_n$ we have $p_n = 4^{-n}p_0$ for $n\geqslant 0$. Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n=1$ we have
$$
p_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4^{-n} = 1
$$
and hence $p_0=\frac34$, so $p_n = 3\cdot 4^{-(n+1)}$ for $n\geqslant 0$. Continuing from your work, we have
$$
\mathbb P(X\geqslant 2) = 1 - (p_0 + p_1) = 1 - (3/4 + 3/16) = 1/16.
$$

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense.